# Filter NSArray with NSPredicate gives always null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm having the following core data entities:

[image]

Now I have NSArray with all POI entities.

I want to filter that array with a predicate so that it searches on every attribute it has to see if it contains something that the user searches.

For example: 
Array object 0 :
address = Test
details = Test1
..

Array object 1:
Address = Ba
details = Ba1
..

and the users searches for the 'e', I want to get an nsarray with only object 0.

I tried like this:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

 searchResults = [_dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

But this returns always nothing.

Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try like this;

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.propertyName contains[cd] %@", searchText];
```

Comment: When using that, I get this error [POI copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to. I think I need to implement that on myself in my classes of Core data.

Comment: Try this; contains[c]

Comment: make sure that searchText is not empty.

Comment: Problem solved. I returned the wrong array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1007522 you are welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer your welcome to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `_dataArray` contains `POI` entities and searching on `address` attribute, change the predicate to

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"address contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

 searchResults = [_dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                            predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] \'%@\'",
                            searchText];

searchResults = [_dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```